# (Hibernate HQL update query) org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found ','

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

HQL query to update table with multiple parameters whereas search for old parameters to update

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">4</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Hibernate code:**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

servlet method {
 SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
.addAnnotatedClass(BollyWood.class)
.addAnnotatedClass(HollyWood.class)
.buildSessionFactory();
Session se = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {
            se.beginTransaction();
            
            
                String query1 = "update hollywood set "
                        + "name = :m_name ,"
                        + "timing = :m_timing ,"
                        + "price = :m_price "
                        + "where name = :mname ,"
                        + "timing = :mtiming ,"
                        + "price = :mprice";


                 // Generating error for `,` separating different parameters
               
                Query query = se.createQuery(query1);
                query.setParameter("m_name", m_name);
                query.setParameter("m_timing", m_timing);
                query.setParameter("m_price", m_price);
                query.setParameter("mname", mname);
                query.setParameter("mtiming", mtiming);
                query.setParameter("mprice", mprice);
    
                query.executeUpdate();
    
            } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            se.close();
            factory.close();
        }
}
```

**Run logs**

```
18-Mar-2023 19:28:37.722 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-9] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database]
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.594 WARN [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver.resolveEntity HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.674 WARN [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.674 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database]
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.675 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.675 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.676 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init> HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 4 (min=1)
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.684 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init> HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.740 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator.initiateService HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.746 ERROR [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError line 1:95: expecting EOF, found ','
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.746 ERROR [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError line 1:95: expecting EOF, found ','
    line 1:95: expecting EOF, found ','
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found ',' near line 1, column 95 [update hollywood set name = :m_name ,timing = :m_timing ,price = :m_price where name = :mname ,timing = :mtiming ,price = :mprice]
        at antlr.Parser.match(Parser.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:215)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:355)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.createQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.AdminChangeServlet.doGet(AdminChangeServlet.java:61)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
18-Mar-2023 19:29:09.838 INFO [http-nio-18080-exec-8] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.stop HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database]
```

**Jars:** hibernate-search-5.8.0.Final and mysql-connector-java-5.1.14

have tried:
1.[Update several Columns in one Hibernate Query? StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296499/update-several-columns-in-one-hibernate-query),

2.[QuerySyntaxException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724073/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-unexpected-token-asf-is-al)

Comment: Where conditions must be concatenated with AND not with comma.

Comment: @Jens i have tried using AND it still generates Error [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: AND ]

Comment: CAn you show the query with and.

Comment: @Jens 
String query1 = "update hollywood set " + "name = :m_name AND " + "timing = :m_timing AND " + "price = :m_price " + "where name = :mname AND " + "timing = :mtiming AND " + "price = :mprice";

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: AND near line 1, column 37 [update hollywood set name = :m_name AND timing = :m_timing AND price = :m_price where name = :mname AND timing = :mtiming AND price = :mprice]

Comment: The set part must be separated with comma and where conditions with AND.

Comment: String query1 = "update hollywood set " + "name = :m_name , " + "timing = :m_timing , " + "price = :m_price " + "where name = :mname AND " + "timing = :mtiming AND " + "price = :mprice";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "where" statement you must not use commas.

your code:

```
    String query1 = "update hollywood set "
            + "name = :m_name ,"
            + "timing = :m_timing ,"
            + "price = :m_price "
            + "where name = :mname ,"
            + "timing = :mtiming ,"
            + "price = :mprice";
```

so it will translate into

```
update hollywood set name = :m_name ,timing = :m_timing ,price = :m_price **where** name = :mname ,timing = :mtiming ,price = :mprice
```

Notice the `where` keyword in the middle.
so, if you want to update name, timing and price **where** name is mname AND timing = mtiming AND price = mprice you should change into the following:

```
        String query1 = "update hollywood set "
                + "name = :m_name ,"
                + "timing = :m_timing ,"
                + "price = :m_price "
                + "where name = :mname AND "
                + "timing = :mtiming AND "
                + "price = :mprice";
```

this will translate into:
update hollywood set name = :m_name ,timing = :m_timing ,price = :m_price **where** name = :mname AND timing = :mtiming AND price = :mprice

**Note:** the space after the `AND` keyword is important